# <mat-slider> touch issue in mobile device

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2

I use material angular  in my website its work good but when I use in a mobile device I face a problem like when I scroll down that time I touch by mistake on mat range slider reason for that my rage was change if I not want

So I want a solution for that like I need only mat-slider value will change when user drag handle of mat-slider instead of clicking slider.

Comment: Are you using `<mat-slider>` or `<mat-slide-toggle>`?

Comment: @GCSDC <mat-slider>

Comment: @GCSDC i want slider not work on click. I want only value change when drag with handle

Comment: I've got it. For `<mat-slide-toggle>` there are properties `disableDragValue` and `disableToggleValue ` which allow this kind of behaviour, for `<mat-slider>`, couldn't find anything near it. Also tried to stop (change) and (input) event propagation to prevent it from being updated on click but didn't have any success on that. Maybe you could try a workaround using `onTouched`, but not sure how.

Comment: @GCSDC there are no properties like disableDragValue and disableToggleValue. I have don’t idea about onTouched how to use this. If you got any solution then please post example on stackbiz

Comment: Did you found any solution? Same issue

Answer (score 0):

This is a workaround, not even close to the normal solution.

You can conditionally hide "range-line" part of a slider and still show only handler (which still will be able to work).

In you scss:

```
::ng-deep {
  .mat-slider {
    height: 0;
    padding: 0;

  .mat-slider-track-wrapper {
    display: none;
    height: 0;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a CSS solution for this that also resolves the issue for Angular. It disables the ability to click on the slider itself, but permits clicking on the thumb/handle:

```
input[type="range"]{
  pointer-events:none;
}
input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  pointer-events:all;
}
input[type="range"]::-moz-range-thumb {
  pointer-events:all;
}
input[type="range"]::-ms-thumb {
  pointer-events:all;
}
```

The related answer is here: [How to make HTML range input's to work only on sliding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50235017/how-to-make-html-range-inputs-to-work-only-on-sliding)